# change the look of site element on sharepoint

Tags: css, sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-2013

I want to change the look of "more options" button, which looks ass thre bricks "..." as the picture below

link to the picture, More cleare

http://s29.postimg.org/f29je10h3/Namnl_sq.png

I have tried to find it in CSS and masterpage files but couldnt find it.

Where can i find it and change it to a word or an icon.

this is the url for the page 
http:///sites/SiteCollectionOne/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via jQuery:

```
$("img.ms-ellipsis-icon").parent().html("<span>Open Menu</span>");
```

You would also need to adapt the width of the parent elements (the a, div and td) to get it to show the whole text. You can do that with something like this:

```
$("img.ms-ellipsis-icon").parent().parent().parent().css("width","80px");
$("img.ms-ellipsis-icon").parent().parent().css("width","80px");
$("img.ms-ellipsis-icon").parent().css("width","80px");
```

I'm sure there must be a better way of doing that last part, but I've tried it with parents("td"), parents("div") and it screws everything up.

Hope it helped!